# SQL How to fill alphanumeric column

Tags: sql, sql-server

hello everyone I am looking for a way to complete a column that has alphanumeric unique ID something like adding a +1 of the last max row, image as example

[image]

but we're talking about 100k rows or so
how to complete the column IDPEP? something like

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.Table(IDPEP)
 SELECT 'IDP' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(IDPEP + 1 AS VARCHAR(6)), 6)
```

but I have no idea how to do it, also this main table is filled through some other queries a trigger that adds IDP + last int value is also an option but  i have no idea how to do it, I'm using Sql server 2012

Comment: why not leave that additional formatting to the front end application and just store an integer primary key / identity column to handle unique numbers?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tanner the source of this table is from SSIS it comes from multiple csv that need to be cleansed and filtered no application fills this table!, ID column is identity but it's not matched with IDPEP

Comment: Do you need insert or update? what values do you have and what are your expected results?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to `insert`, you want to `update`.  In SQL Server, you can do:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from dbo.table t
     )
update toupdate
    set idpep = 'IDP' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(seqnum + 1 AS VARCHAR(6)), 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, part of the solution here would be to ensure that all data inserted into the table is done so ultimately via the same channel.

I'm not sure if it would be possible in your environment, but the way I'd probably implement this would be to have all data inserted into a staging table, and then have a stored procedure that both adds the new ID and processes the data into the destination table. This is a fairly typical approach to data warehousing.

There are probably many ways you could add the new ID, e.g., get the last ID from the destination table and then use the `ROW_NUMBER` function to calculate an increment for each record.